# Not able to set orientation in ipad app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, ios5

I'm using ios6 version for generating a new Ipad app. In my app i'm creating a split view. That split view has to always in a landscape mode. App is working in ipad 6.0 simulator. But not working in ipad 5.0 simulator. I want to run the app both ipad 6.0 and ipad 5.0.

I'm using this code

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
     return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

-(BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
     return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do in ios6 like this way:-

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

and check every time in `ViewWillApear` device Oriantation like:-

```
- (void)willRotateToOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)newOrientation {
        if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
        {
            if (newOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || newOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {

              //set your landscap View Frame
                [self supportedInterfaceOrientations];

            }



        }
        else if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
        {
            if(newOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || newOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){
      //set your Potrait View Frame
                [self supportedInterfaceOrientations];

            }
        }
        // Handle rotation
    }


    -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [self willRotateToOrientation:[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]];  
        [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    }
```

**UPDATE**

likely people use checking device`orientation` like below way in putting this line in to `ViewWillApear`:-

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(deviceRotated:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

and

```
-(void)deviceRotated:(NSNotification*)notification
{

    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        //Do your stuff for landscap
    }
    else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
      //Do your stuff for potrait

    }

}
```

**IN IOS5 only landscap you can do like bellow:**

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {


        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        return NO;
    }
}

if you wish to support all oriantation you need to just return YES  like:-

 -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

            return YES;  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 5.0 you should use:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

Comment: Just place it next to your methods described in your question.

Comment: I don't think that's going to work. That line should be: return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);

Comment: UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape is defined as (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight). Take a look at the UIApplication Class Reference.